# RTL8188CE - Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: wireless, drivers, realtek

I am running "Zorin OS 7 Core" on my Laptop, which is based on Ubuntu 13.04.

I have a problem with my RTL8188CE WiFi card. It says "wireless is disabled by hardware switch", but I already [installed this driver](https://github.com/FreedomBen/rtl8188ce-linux-driver) correctly.

I did it the same way I had done it on 12.04, and it worked.
The crazy thing is when I type:

```
rfkill list all
```

It says:

```
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes
1: asus-wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

_

```
 rfkill unblock all
```

Didn’t help... I don’t know why it shows me 2 WiFi devices and why I can't unblock the `phy0`

Does anyone have an idea?

My Notebook Specs are :

```
Manufacturer : ASUS 
Modell : F75VB-TY041H 
Prozessor : Intel Core i5-3230M (3. Gen) 
Graphic : Intel HD 4000 / NVIDIA GeForce GT 740M 
wlan : Realtek RTL8188CE WLAN Adapter 
Audio : Realtek Audio ALC269 
BIOS : v. 304
```

Comment: The hardware switch is usually a button on your keyboard, so have you made sure you've pressed that button? Sorry if it's irrelevant, I'm not too good with command-line diagnostics.

Comment: I already tried it, the button is Fn+F2 to activate the Wifi but it dont help

Comment: I see. In that case, I can't help you but I hope you get your answer soon :)

Comment: Ok i got the Solution!

you need to change a GRUB config

1.Step

sudo gedit /etc/default/grub

2.Step , edit GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT to:

GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet acpi_osi=Linux acpi_backlight=vendor splash"

3. Step Do the

sudo update-grub and then

Restart your Computer

Comment: Cool. Why don't you add that as an answer? You're absolutely encouraged to answer your own question.

Comment: i cant i am to new and not allowed to answear my own question :D

Comment: Now that I look at it, you should ask the question [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/). Cheers